# RecyclerView notifydatasetchanged freeze the UI for some seconds in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a vertical `RecyclerView` with each item having horizontal `RecyclerView` .

When i am updating the `RecyclerView` UI Freeze for some seconds.

**update code :**

```
public void setData(List<SectionList> data) {
        if (this.sectionListDetails != data) {
            this.sectionListDetails = data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am guessing because recyclerview tends to call the whole onBindViewHolder when using notifyDataSetChanged(). Thus resulting the recyclerview inside the recyclerview to re - initialize itself.

Comment: Are you changing all of the section list? if not, why not update the only item that needs to be updated.

Comment: if spesific items of your list is changed you can use notifyItemChanged(position) or if you insterted new items you can use notifyItemRangeInserted methods to avoid notify whole items with notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @Vryin yes i have to update all the sectionlist

Comment: Maybe the problem is how your items look like. Are there any images in your items which you load synchronously? If yes, try to use AsyncTask or something like that to load the images asyncronously.

Comment: @beeb No simple i am loading textview.

Comment: In Android 7.0 it's working fine. But below 7.0 it's taking some time to load.

Comment: Are you running the notifyDataSetChanged in onPostExecute or something?

Comment: @Vryin i am using retrofit for networking. I am loading it on Success

Comment: Can you please post the whole code?

Answer (score 2):

Using `RecyclerView` in `RecyclerView` is what is making it processing intensive and causing delayed rendering of views on screen. Also the computing comnplexity of your both adapter code matters how Android framework will execute it. But i think instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` (which re-renders displayed items and also the nested horizontal adapter in every row which is apparently processing intensive) try using following methods which can help reduce unnecessary processing

```
notifyItemChanged(int)
notifyItemInserted(int)
notifyItemRemoved(int)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)
notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)
```

using which  you can taget to specific item(s). [Check this link for more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int))

Comment: Try observing logcat, bdw threre are also other affecting factors such as how powerful device is and that data is missing in question. Still i'd say try giving a shot to those methods.